# Any way to open part of a page in window.open()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an html page and basically it contains 2 div blocks and 2 links. Now, when I click one link then the content of first div should get opened in a new window. Similarly, when I click second link content of second div should get opened in another new window.

Here's a code - http://jsfiddle.net/PAJWV/5/

I do agree that it is impossible, but in case there is a workaround. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function printPage(divid)
{
elementId=divid;

var printContent = document.getElementById(elementId);

var windowUrl = 'about:blank';

var uniqueName = new Date();

var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();

var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName,'left=500,top=500,width=500,height=500');



printWindow.document.write('<html><head></head><body>'+printContent.innerHTML+'</body></html>');




}
```

Try above code by calling the function onclick

Answer (score 1):

Just create a page with the content from `div1` inside of it and call your script to open this page. Same thing with `div2`.

You can pull the content from another file for `div1` using an iframe and do the same for `div2`.

Why can't you do it this way?

Comment: I can't do this way because sometimes I have to show both the divs on the same page. Just for presentation purpose I have inserted 2 links but there will be no links in my app and the divs will be dynamically generated.

Comment: Then you can create two display templates and show it in one view When you need show both templates

Comment: @sasha - The contents of 2 divs are huge and due to performance issues I can't include both of them on same window when I just need to display one.

Comment: I can even remove the "not required" div using javascript on page load. This solution is in my list. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

http://jsfiddle.net/PAJWV/9/

will not run fine in jsfiddle but will run fine with actual code due to some limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt try this but you can link as

window.open("index.html#second");

and along with that hiding other divs with id not #second will work fine

Comment: This wont work, when the content of my 2 divs are huge enough. Unnecessarily I will loading data on the 2 pages and will create performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

you can create separate html for div1 and div2 like

**window1.html**

```
<body>
    <div id="first">
    First Div contents.
  </div>
</body
```

**window2.html**

```
<body>
    <div id="second">
    second Div contents.
  </div>
</body
```

**main.html**

```
<div>
    <a id="link1" href="window.open('window1.html')">Open div 1</a><br />
    <a id="link2" href="window.open('window2.html')">Open div 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand this is pretty straight forward. But I can't do this way as sometimes I have to show both the divs on the same page. Also I don't want to use any kind of frames.

Comment: Actually as much i know you cant pass html to pop.